# Cannot install ADAL VS Community 2017

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, adal

When I try to install ADAL to my new VS Cross Platform Project I get the following error:

Error Could not install package ‘Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.13.1’. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets ‘.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111’, but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I understand that the fix is to remove support for Windows Phone 8.1 in the shared project properties, however this is the issue I am having. I can see the supported platforms list, but I cannot edit all of it, so I appear to be stuck with Profile111, or 259, Does anyone know how to work around this issue please?

This is Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, new project, Xamarin Forms, with PCL. Targets .Net 4.5, using the latest pre-release of Xamarin.Forms.

I need to get Azure AD Auth working in a PCL project, and this is the best solution.

[image: project properties screen]

[image: Selection list of removable items.]

Comment: Could you a ,net standard library instead of a pcl?

Comment: @KenTucker, I have no idea to be honest, this is the default for any new Xamarin forms PCL project. I downloaded the ADAL sample from the Xamarin blog, that was the same once it had been opened in VS2017. There seems to be no way to remove the Win Phone 8 support in VS community, and I don't know which profile would still work with no loss of features for Android, iOS and UWP.

Comment: @KenTucker, no. I tried that and ended up with profile49, I think, and it wasn't working, removed the .net core and ended up on profile24, which also fails :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this issue is caused that profile111 is not supported. This is because WinPhone8.1 is not supported by ADAL. The library only support **Profile7** at present.( refer [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/496))

If you want this library to support for the profile111, I suggest that you reopen a new issue from [GitHub for this library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues).

Comment: I got Profile7 by installing VS2015 and making the necessary changes. Thanks for the link.